# Monitoring never ending Python script using New Relic

Tags: python, newrelic, supervisord

I have a python script that runs under [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). The script is basically a never ending consumer that would keep on listening to some channel forever. Is it possible to monitor this kind of script using New Relic for Python?

Answer (score 0):

The agent isn't going to handle infinite loops well. If it treats your application as a single transaction it will never finish and report its metrics.

You can use the agent, but you should manually wrap the functions.
Here is a document that should show you how to go about this:
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/supported-features/python-background-tasks